# Change specific locations in RGB image to a particular color based on index locations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rgb

I have a 2336x3504 RGB uint8 file in MATLAB. I also have a vector consisting of pixels of interest in index notation (based on a 2336x3504 binary image). I want all points in the RGB image that correspond to those pixels of interest to be set to a particular color.

My first thought was to do the following:

```
% Separate RGB image into three 3 uint8 arrays.

RGB1 = RGBImage(:,:,1);

RGB2 = RGBImage(:,:,2);

RGB3 = RGBImage(:,:,3);

% Change each layer based on the color I want (say for red, or [255 0 0])

RGB1(interestPixels) = 255;

RGB2(interestPixels) = 0;

RGB3(interestPixels) = 0;

% Then put it all back together

NewRGBImage = cat(3,RGB1,RGB2,RGB3);
```

While this works, it seems messy. I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could find so far is this:

```
% test init
mat = randi(3,[2 4 3]);        % a 3-channel 2x4 image
interest_pix = [1 1;2 2; 1 3]; % some pixel coordinates

channel_selector = ones(1,size(interest_pix,1));
inds_chn1 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),1*channel_selector);
inds_chn2 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),2*channel_selector);
inds_chn3 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),3*channel_selector);

mat(inds_chn1)=255;    % you could also use NaN or Inf to make the changes more apparent
mat(inds_chn2)=0;
mat(inds_chn3)=0;
```

The advantage of this approach is that it does not create new matrices for the channels.

Reading material: [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html;jsessionid=236260c63222dd295e27e5284d5f).

Answer (score 0):

Above code has errors. Here is the correct one.Try it.

```
function testmat=testmat()
mat = rand(3,3,3)% a 3-channel 2x4 image
[v w c]=size(mat)
interest_pix = [1 1;2 2; 1 3]; % some pixel coordinates

channel_selector = ones(1,size(interest_pix,1));
c1=1*channel_selector;
d1(:,1)=c1(1,:);

c2=2*channel_selector;
d2(:,1)=c2(1,:)

c3=3*channel_selector;
d3(:,1)=c3(1,:);

inds_chn1 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),1*d1);
inds_chn2 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),1*d2);
inds_chn3 = sub2ind(size(mat),interest_pix(:,1), interest_pix(:,2),1*d3);

mat(inds_chn1)=255;    % you could also use NaN or Inf to make the changes more apparent
mat(inds_chn2)=0;
mat(inds_chn3)=0;
end
```